# Trouble with the love thread Geralt-the Witcher 3

Tags: the-witcher-3

Maybe someone knows.  If she was having an affair with Triss (kiss, and chose the options „llet's try again”) and she left for Kovir anyway, did the love thread come up with her?  In addition, Yen was rejected.

I mean the quest ‚ Now or never’.  We help the magicians escape from Novigrad.  When saying goodbye to Triss, I chose the options ’ let's try it again’.  However, she didn’t return.  Does this mean that my Gerlat won’t be in a relationship with Triss?

Does he have to come back to be with her at the end of the game?

Comment: I can help, but ì you make it clearer, I will answer it, I gave you an upvote!

Comment: Hi Karla, please clarify your question a bit more and then we'll be able to answer it. I've read most of the books and I still can't understand who you are talking about or what scenario you're trying to describe.

Comment: I explained more.

Comment: @Karla Thanks, that should be enough to get your question re-opened. Once enough people have voted to reopen it, I have enough information now to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In order to start the Triss romance quest, the player needs to have completed "The Play's the Thing" main quest, which will allow them to start a sidequest called "A Matter of Life and Death." Triss and Geralt will need to attend a masquerade in order to save a young alchemist. During the masquerade, Geralt will need to be complimentary throughout the ball and must kiss Triss when the fireworks start.

You still get dialogue options to infer that you love Triss, but if you didn't kiss her during the "A Matter of Life and Death" quest, you'll have no option to have Triss as a romance option. The only thing you can do is reload a save to before the quest and try again.